# In a Python 3 virtual environment I have added a mypaths.pth file within the site-packages dir but the dirs in the pth file are not added to sys.path

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

The mypaths.pth is in the following directory:

```
main>venv>lib>python3.8>site-packages>mypaths.pth
```

mypaths.pth includes lines similar to the following:

```
/home/user/dev/modules/lib/
/home/user/dev/modules/entity/
/home/user/dev/myConfig/
```

The directories all exist, but none of them are added to the sys.path in the python sessions.

Is the use of a name.pth file different in a virtual environment? Or, more basically, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to put this out there to show how ignorant I was being. I put the mypaths.pth file in the virtual environment structure and then executed the python scripts by a terminal in the system level python, i.e. without activating my virtual environment. So, feeling a little embarrassed.